# KendoUI Export to PDF

Tags: kendo-ui, pdf-generation

I am trying to make use of 'Export PDF' functionality for a KendoUI grid. The following is the code in my grid configuration:

```
            pdf: {
                allPages: true,
                fileName: "feesandcosts.pdf",
                proxyURL: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/export"
            },
```

When I click the 'Export PDF' button the grid grays and disables out. When I try to test the URL by navigating to it directly in the web browser it seems to be a broken hyperlink.

Can some one help guide me?

Answer (score 0):

This is the description of the proxyURL from API reference. In summary is an optional setting for browsers that dont support local save of files and if you use it you should implement the functionalty.

> pdf.proxyURL String (default: null)
>
> The URL of the server side proxy which will stream the file to the end
>   user.
>
> A proxy will be used when the browser isn't capable of saving files
>   locally e.g. Internet Explorer 9 and Safari. PDF export is not
>   supported in Internet Explorer 8 and below.
>
> The developer is responsible for implementing the server-side proxy.
>
> The proxy will receive a POST request with the following parameters in
>   the request body:
>
> contentType: The MIME type of the file base64: The base-64 encoded
>   file content fileName: The file name, as requested by the caller. The
>   proxy should return the decoded file with the "Content-Disposition"
>   header set to attachment; filename="".